# Neo4j and Spring-data Map query result to Jackson JsonNode

Tags: neo4j, jackson, cypher, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

How would I use neo4j and spring-data in order to convert the value of a cypher query to JsonNode (Jackson).

Example query:

```
Match (a:Moo)
return {
    id: id(a),
    list: [{color: a.color}, {color: a.otherColor}]
}
```

I want the result of the query to be transformed to Json (preferably JsonNode of Jackson)

Since the result is already in json format and it is transfered in json format this should be fairly easy, yet I haven't been able to find hsolutionhow to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could always post your cypher to the [neo4j transactional end point](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.0-M04/rest-api-transactional.html).

If you posted something like this...

```
{
  "statements": [
    {
      "statement": "match (a:Moo {name: 'A'}) RETURN {id: id(a)} as id, {list : [{colour: a.colour}, {colour: a.other_colour}]} as list"
    }
  ]
}
```

you would get back something like this...

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "columns": [
        "id",
        "list"
      ],
      "data": [
       {
         "row": [
             {"id" : 2723},
             {"list" :
               [
                 {"colour" : "black"},
                 {"colour" : "blue"}
               ]
             }
         ]
       },
       {
         "row": [
             {"id" : 2724},
             {"list" :
               [
                 {"colour" : "green"},
                 {"colour" : "purple"}
               ]
             }
         ]
       }
     ]
   }
 ],
 "errors": [ ]
}
```

Or you can do something like this if you want the property values combined in same object you could post this cypher and get back

```
{
  "statements": [
    {
      "statement": "match (a:Moo {name: 'A'}) RETURN {id: id(a), list: [ {colour: a.colour},{colour: a.other_colour}]} as data"
    }
  ]
}
```

And have something like this returned

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "columns": [
        "data"
      ],
      "data": [
       {
         "row": [
             {"id" : 2723,
             "list" :
               [
                 {"colour" : "black"},
                 {"colour" : "blue"}
               ]
             }
         ]
       },
       {
         "row": [
             {"id" : 2724,
             "list" :
               [
                 {"colour" : "green"},
                 {"colour" : "purple"}
               ]
             }
         ]
       }
     ]
   }
 ],
 "errors": [ ]
}
```

Comment: Not really what im looking for since I want nested objects as well... the example has only two levels of objects, but I want to use it for a larger finitely nested objects

Comment: I updated the query and response to include the property names in the data. Closer?

Comment: Finite. No infinite... how would my example select look if I used it here? Would it simply be a row per object... cause thats what im looking for?

Comment: heh - yeah, noticed that after - deleted that part - apologies

Comment: i updated the response to show another node returned with an id and a collection of colours

Comment: I want only one column containing nested objects like in the original example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72097/discussion-between-dave-bennett-and-nayish).

Comment: Looking for a spring-data solution